# $\int_0^1|f_n|^3\leq 1\Rightarrow \int_E |f_n|<\varepsilon$ when $|E|$ is small

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, uniform-integrability

Let $f_n\colon [0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be Lebesgue measurable with $$\int_0^1|f_n|^3\leq 1 \mbox{ for all } n.$$ Show that for all $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ so that if $E\subset[0,1]$ is Lebesgue measurable with $|E|<\delta$ then $$\int_E |f_n|<\varepsilon\mbox{ for all } n$$

Comment: Do you know [Hölder's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder's_inequality)?

Comment: Yes, I do, why?

Comment: Then try to apply it to get an upper bound of your integral in terms of $|E|$ and $L^3$-norm of $f_n$

Comment: Its true, thank you very much. How do I have an example that the conclusion is false if to replace $\|f\|_3\leq 1$ to $\|f_n\|_1\leq 1$?

Comment: You are welcome. What about $f_n=n\cdot\chi_{E_n}$, where $|E_n|=\frac{1}{n}$?

Answer (score 3):

I don't want to give away the whole answer, but use that $\displaystyle \int_E |f_n|=\int_{[0,1]}\chi_E|f_n|$ and try to use the Holder's inequality hint on the right side (what should $q$ be?).

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you know an example that the conclusion is false if to replace $\|f\|_3\leq 1$ to $\|f_n\|_1\leq 1$?

Answer (score -4):

I would complete proof of JLA. Suppose $ p=3 $ and then Using the equality $ \frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} =1 $ we have $ q= \frac{3}{2}$. We can write
$$ \int_E |f_n|=\int_{[0,1]}\chi_E|f_n| \leq \left(\int_{[0,1]}{|f_n|^3}\right)^\frac{1}{3} \left(\int_{[0,1]}{\chi_E}^{\frac{3}{2}}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}$$

Comment: -1. Compare "I would complete proof of JLA" with "I don't want to give away the whole answer".